# L'étiquette [phrase]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Je viens de découvrir l'existence de l'étiquette [phrase](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase). Je pense qu'on fait mieux de supprimer l'étiquette de ces questions et la remplacer par [locutions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locutions) ; c'est évident que les PO ont voulu référer au sujet de locutions.

En tout cas, je trouve l'étiquette [phrase](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) assez vague : c'est un faux ami et hors contexte, je n'ai aucune idée si le PO réfère à une locution ou à un énoncé complet. Donc, je pense que la synonymisation ne convienne pas. Mais si l'on ne la synonymise pas avec [locutions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locutions), comment prévenir que les PO ne l'utilisent encore, s'ils ont assez de la réputation pour créer les étiquettes ? On doit éviter l'utilisation simultanée de plusieurs étiquettes qui réfèrent à la même chose.

Answer (score 2):

**Phrases** (***sentences***) et **locutions**/expressions/groupes de mots (***phrases***) sont des choses différentes.

Si des questions sont mal « taguées » ou utilisent autrement *phrase* de manière incorrecte, il vaut mieux les corriger plutôt que de supprimer un tag sous prétexte qu'il s'agit d'un faux ami.

Supprimer le tag ne résoudrait de toute façon pas cette erreur fréquente.

Comment: To be precise, I'm referring to removing/deleting the tag from the _question_, rather than entirely. It's not a bad idea anyway, but I would like to see if there's anything else worth doing to reduce future occurrences of this mistake.

Comment: Removing/replacing an irrelevant tag from a question is encouraged. Maybe an English short warning in the *phrase* tag description line would help avoiding this confusion.

Comment: I agree with the idea of adding a disclaimer on both tag descriptions. You guys feel free to suggest some sentences if you feel inspired!

Comment: @Reyedy Maybe sth like (Warning: French ***phrase*** means **sentence**, use the ***locutions*** or ***expressions*** tags for the English **phrase**.)